# dependency resolution (CentOs - Yum)

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies

I'm trying to install a package that depends on Java 1.7 with yum.
I do I have Java 7 on my machine:

```
#echo $JAVA_HOME
$JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.3.4.1.el6_3-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

But `yum` still complains about not finding `java 1.7`:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: <some package>
           Requires: jre >= 1.7.0
           Available: java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0-29.1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               jre = 1.5.0
           Available: 1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.45.1.11.1.el6.x86_64 (base)
               jre = 1.6.0
           Available: 1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.48.1.11.3.el6_2.x86_64 (updates)
               jre = 1.6.0
           Available: 1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.49.1.11.4.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               jre = 1.6.0
           Available: 1:java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-1.50.1.11.5.el6_3.x86_64 (updates)
               jre = 1.6.0
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
<some package>.noarch has missing requires of jre >= ('0', '1.6.0', None)
```

Any idea as to what might caused this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I know that you installed java, but maybe you should try running `sudo yum install java` to make sure yum "remembers" installing it.

**EDIT

You could also try running `sudo rpmdb --rebuilddb` to rebuild the rpm database.**

Comment: I ran `rpmdb --rebuildb`, still doesn't seem to help. And are you suggesting remove the current java and run `yum install java` ?

Comment: @OneTwoThree Either that, or run `yum install java` without uninstalling java. OBTW, did you install java with yum?

Comment: No, I installed with `rpm`

Comment: @OneTwoThree Well try installing it with `sudo yum localinstall <rpm-file>`.